# React lazy with TypeScript and Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, lazy-loading

I have a problem with combining React lazy with my project that uses TypeScript and Redux. Here is my code:

```
// lazy-area.tsx
const LazyArea = ({text}: Props): JSX.Element => {
    ....
};

export const LazyArea = connect(
mapStateToProps,
mapDispatchToProps
)(LazyArea);


//Menu.tsx
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from 'react';
....
const lazyArea = lazy(() => import('./lazy-area'));

const Menu = ({
    .....
  }: Props): JSX.Element | null => {
      return (
        <Suspense fallback={LoadingView}>
            <LazyArea />
        </Suspense>
      )
    export const Menu = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
    )(Menu);
});
```

With this set up I get an error saying:

```
Type 'Promise<typeof import("/home/user/app/lazy-area")>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<{ default: ComponentType<any>; }>'.
  Property 'default' is missing in type 'typeof import("/home/user/app/src/lazy-area")' but required in type '{ default: ComponentType<any>; }'.
```

I have tried solutions presented in:
[TypeScript with React Lazy getting promise error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55982648/typescript-with-react-lazy-getting-promise-error)
to add `export as ComponentType<any>` and `export as React.FC` to LazyArea export but error stays the same.

The solution presented in 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54150819/using-react-lazy-with-typescript/54196049)
removes the error but according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55948860/react-lazy-with-typescript) the solution is def not best practice and "may kill optimizations and potentially result in infinite loop".

This error also goes away when using export default in LazyArea:

```
const LazyArea = connect(
mapStateToProps,
mapDispatchToProps
)(LazyArea);

export default LazyArea;
```

However I have read from some sources that using export default should be avoided.

Is there any good solution to get past this problem? Please inform if I have presented too little info about something. Thanks :)

Comment: The sad truth is React.lazy in the current state intended to work only with default exports. Any way you trying to do it - is a hacky workaround to pretend we have a default export. The hacky workaround which is considered the best for now mentioned in the docs itself (https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#named-exports)

Comment: alright, I guess using default export will just have to do then. Thanks :)

Comment: Nice first question!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you think using default exports should be avoided :) I think it's just a convention that some teams have. So adding `export default LazyArea;` is a valid way to deal with this. You won't have too many lazy modules anyway.

That's why the solution from [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#named-exports) could also work where you just put that default export into its own file.

The other recommended approach is to change import code to convert it to default inline:

```js
const LazyArea = React.lazy(() =>
  import("./lazy-area").then((module) => ({
    default: module.LazyArea,
  }))
);
```

But that's seems like too much work for me :) So I created [react-lazily](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lazily) which does what you would expect.

#### Example

```js
const { LazyArea } = lazily(() => import('./lazy-area'));
```

it's just a small wrapper around `React.lazy`, but it allows you to have a really straight forward code, like that:

```
import { lazily } from 'react-lazily';
const { Component1, Component2 } = lazily(() => import('./Components'))
```